# Python: Fixed length string multiple variables left/right aligned

Tags: python, string, format

I am fairly new to Python and try to format a string for ouput on a LCD-display.

I would like to output a formatted table of train departures

- the display has a fixed length of 20 characters (20x4)
- I have 3 string-variables with variable length (line, station, eta)
- 2 of them should be left-aligned (line, station), while the third one should go right aligned

Example:

```
8: station A       8
45: long station  10
1: great station  25
```

I have played around with various things, but I am not able to define the max length for the overall string, but only 1 variable:

```
print('{0}: {1} {2:<20}'.format(line, station, eta))
```

Any tips and hints are much appreciated!

**--- Solution based on @Rafael Cardoso s answer:**

```
print(format_departure(line, station, eta))


def format_departure(line, station, eta):
    max_length = 20
    truncate_chars = '..'

    # add a leading space to the eta - just to be on the safe side
    eta = ' ' + eta

    output = '{0}: {1}'.format(line, station)  # aligns left

    # make sure that the first part is not too long, otherwise truncate
    if (len(output + eta)) > max_length:
        # shorten for truncate_chars + eta + space
        output = output[0:max_length - len(truncate_chars + eta)] + truncate_chars

    output = output + ' '*(max_length - len(output) - len(eta)) + eta  # aligns right

    return output
```

Comment: Have a look at `tabulate:` http://txt.arboreus.com/2013/03/13/pretty-print-tables-in-python.html (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add spaces by making a calculation of how many spaces should be added in between station and eta :

```
>>> line = ['8', '45', '1']
>>> station = ['station A', 'long station', 'great station']
>>> eta = ['8','10', '25']
>>> MAX = 20

>>> for i in range(3):
    m_str = '{0}: {1}'.format(line[i], station[i]) #aligns left
    m_str = m_str + ' '*(MAX-len(str)-len(eta[i])) + eta[i] #aligns right
    print m_str
```

The calculation would be to get the max length (in this case 20) minus the current `len` of m_str minus what will yet come (`len(eta[i])`).

Bear in mind that it assumes that `len(m_str)` will not be greater than 20 at this point.

Output:

```
8: station A       8
45: long station  10
1: great station  25
```

Comment: I took your proposal and added some functionality to also account for line/station strings too long to display nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary string for the left part and its length:

```
tmp = '{}: {}'.format(line, station)
print('{}{:{}}'.format(tmp, eta, 20-len(tmp)))
```

Demo:

```
trains = ((8, 'station A', 8), (45, 'long station', 10), (1, 'great station', 25))
for line, station, eta in trains:
    tmp = '{}: {}'.format(line, station)
    print('{}{:{}}'.format(tmp, eta, 20-len(tmp)))

Prints:

8: station A       8
45: long station  10
1: great station  25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slices to specify a max length.  E.g. the following will only print the first 20 characters of the string resulting from the format:

```
print('{0}: {1} {2:<20}'.format(line, station, eta)[:20])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.rjust()` and `.ljust()` methods on given strings to set their alignment,

```
lst = [[8, "station A", 8], [45, "long station", 10], [1, "great station", 25]]
for i in lst:
    print str(i[0]).ljust(2)+":"+i[1]+str(i[2]).rjust(20 - (len(i[1])+3))
```

Output:

```
8 :station A       8
45:long station   10
1 :great station  25
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you wish to create  a table, so I suggest you use `prettytable` like so:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable(['line', 'station', 'eta'])

table.add_row([8, 'station A', 10])
table.add_row([6, 'station B', 20])
table.add_row([5, 'station C', 15])
```

As it is not built in to Python, you will need to install it yourself from the package index [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable).

Comment: Don't we need to import something for `prettyTable` ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal Thanks for the edit. What do you think of the library?

Comment: You are right, but I prefer including as few libraries as possible